# MySQL Selecting multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, in-clause

I have two tables.

Users - Has 2 foreign keys `reg_ip` and `last_ip` which both reference the second table column `id`.

users

```
+--------+---------+
| reg_ip | last_ip |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |       2 |
+--------+---------+
```

ips

```
+----+---------+
| id | user_ip |
+----+---------+
|  1 | 1.2.3.4 |
|  2 | 2.3.4.5 |
+----+---------+
```

I have been trying to query in such a way that it will return 1.2.3.4 and 2.3.4.5 in one result but I have not been successful. I would be appreciative for a working answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.user_ip)
FROM ips i 
INNER JOIN users u ON i.id IN (u.reg_ip, u.last_ip)
```

Comment: Thank you, though that is returning two rows. I'm looking for a one row response.